# Format of multiline parameter list in Java

Tags: java, indentation

I use K&R indent style. I have following case

```
class X {

    // V1
    public function y(param1, param2, param3, param4,
        param5, param6, param7, param8) {
        statement;
        ...
    }

    // V2
    public function y(param1, param2, param3, param4,
            param5, param6, param7, param8) {
        statement;
        ...
    }

    // V3
    public function y(param1, param2, param3, param4,
        param5, param6, param7, param8
    ) {
        statement;
        ...
    }

    // V4
    public function y(
        param1, param2, param3, param4,
        param5, param6, param7, param8
    ) {
        statement;
        ...
    }

}
```

In V1, second line is aligned with statements in the function, so it is confusing. In V2, this problem is tried to be overcome by adding one level of indentation to the second line of parameter list. Still, the border between parameter list and statement is not obvious. In V3, closing parenthesis moved to new line to create a distinction between parameter list and statement in the function body. In V4, opening parenthesis is also left alone as its closing counterpart to create harmony (I use this format for other parts in the code).

Which format should I use? Do you have any other recommendation?

Comment: I don't think this is good question for stack overfllow. Maybe code review or programmers.

Comment: Near cross site duplicate of [this](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/331680/131624)

Comment: Taking this much parameter is not good, I am aware of it but I do wonder what I asked...

Comment: It's good to know how to do this well even if it isn't the best thing to do.  Wish more people used whitespace to make it readable.  It makes it easier for me to fix when I come along later.

Comment: @CandiedOrange In the link you gave, what is the "form 6"?

Comment: @Mehmed It's from a [wiki.c2.com page on parameter indentation](http://wiki.c2.com/?IndentationOfParameters).  Scroll down until you see **form 6**.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, to say that, but the *real* answer is: read a good book on code quality, like "Clean Code" by Robert Martin. And then start re-factoring your code base.

In good OO design, your goal is to have methods taking **zero** arguments. Occasionally, you allow for one, maybe two, rarely 3 arguments. Anything beyond that carries the heavy code smell of you doing something really wrong. 8 parameters is simply insane.

If you are forced to deal with some "legacy" code, then the answer is: sit down with the team responsible for this code; and then define that **formatter** that gives you a result that everybody can life with. Then make sure that your tooling automatically runs the formatter upon each commit for example.

The core point is: formatting is (almost) always a *style only" question. There is no correct or wrong way of doing it (as humans can really adapt to many different styles). Thus: you look out for what the majority of people wants to see, and then you implement that.

Comment: This function is basically inserts a record in the database, so the parameters are columns. What is the best solution for this case? (Should I create another class for the record and use an instance as parameter?)

Comment: Arity isn't good but it happens.  When it does using whitespace well will at least help others fix it later.  Let's not ignore problems that can't be seen from an ivory tower.

Comment: @CandiedOrange I think writing an answer and giving alternatives is the opposite of ignoring a problem.

Comment: @Mehmed One quick idea: what about using a Map (key: column name, value: column value to insert) ... probably that would need to be extended to allow for types, but be *one* potential way of going here. But of course - be pragmatic. You dont start reworking your code because somebody on SO tells you to do so. You do it because you think it would be the right solution!

Answer (score -2):

This is just formating to the code , it will not affect on the code execution . Use v1 or v2 or just press ctrl+shift+f in eclipse to format your code.

Comment: He asks about formatting. Nowhere in his question he is worried about code execution. Sorry, your answer is really not worth being called an answer.